# Enlarge edittext in android by code when click a button

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to know if its possible to enlarge a EditText in android from 0 until to fill its parent. I tried several things, but in the moment I have the LinearLayout and the EditText is added by code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_buscarenlace"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="right" >
```

-

```
EditText et = (EditText) new EditText(this.act);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) this.act.findViewById(R.id.ll_buscarenlace);

    et.setWidth(0);
    ll.addView(et);

    for (int i=0; i<=ll.getWidth(); i++){
        et.setWidth(i);
        Thread.sleep(50);

    }
```

But this is one of many things that I tried to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: All these codes are in one java file? Please say no.

Comment: I don't seem to see any TextView being added? You're adding an EditText not a TextView. Or am I missing something?

Comment: if you have more than one file. Please seperate it while posting here. Readers can't understand which code in which file.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15182274/321697)

Comment: These are in Layouts folder and src folder, as you know. Sorry, its a EditText, not TextView, Im so tired... This are two separate files, as you know

Comment: Another issue is Thread.sleep(50); This is very small time value. Because it is in miliseconds. 50ms is equal **0.05** secs When this code work correctly it seems like flash. If you try 5 seconds change value to 5000

Comment: Why are you set LinearLayout's with to 0? Are not you trying resize EditText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution: ScaleAnimation.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 1, 1);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
editText.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Not exactly what you're looking for since it *scales* rather than expands, but it may be of help. The effect is not bad either.

Comment: Nothing but excellent! Thank you f20k. Anyway, I added a modification to move from right to left:   Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1,1,1,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

Answer (score 0):

By "make it go from zero to fill-parent", do you mean that you want it to initially be invisible and then, on a button click, become visible?

If so, you don't need to do any resizing - in the layout file set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and make it invisible with `android:visibility="gone"`.

Then, in the onClickListener on your button, you can call `et.setVisible(Visibility.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: I think he wants to animate it.

Comment: drewmore: I want, as kcoppock says, "animated" or something like that. Check the search button in this page: http://www.fastcodesign.com/